# Is a constant function a measurable function?

Tags: measure-theory

I am just starting the section on measurable function and right after the definition of a measurable function I have this question...

Let $(X,\cal{A} _1)$ and $(Y,\cal{A}_2)$ be measurable spaces, and let $f:X_1 \to X_2$ be a constant function. Show that $f$ is $(\cal{A}_1-\cal{A}_2)$-measurable.

What I have tried is the following:

Let $f(x)=c$, $\forall x\in X_1$ and $c\in X_2$

$$\{x:f(x)=c\}=X_1 \in \cal{A}_1$$
$$\{x:f(x)\not = c\}=\emptyset \in \cal{A}_1$$

I don't know if this is correct, but if it is correct then...

**Why is this equivalent to the definition of $(\cal{A}_1-\cal{A}_2)$-measurable?**
i.e. $f^{-1}(U)\in \cal{A}_1$, $\forall U\in \cal{A}_2$

Comment: What you tried is correct on its own but cannot be marked as an acceptable proof of the measurability of $f$. For this you must simply apply the definition that you mention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that $\mathcal{A}_1$ is a sigma algebra for the set $X_1$ then $X_1 \in \mathcal{A}_1$. Then as you noted if $f: X_1 \to X_2$ is constant say $f(x)=c$ for all $x \in X_1$. Let $U \in \mathcal{A}_2$ then $c \in U$ or $c \notin U$, if $c \in U$ then $f^{-1}(U)=X_1$ otherwise $f^{-1}(U) = \emptyset$. Both sets are in $\mathcal{A}_1$ and hence f is measurable.

Comment: My only problem with this approach is when you say $f^{-1}(c)=X_1\in\mathcal{A}_1$
$c$ is an element of $X$ in this case and not a set in $\mathcal{A_2}$ which doesn't work with the definition...

Comment: is this a Borel sigma algebra?

Comment: No it's just an unspecified sigma algebra.

Comment: @Malcolm Sorry, I was being sloppy. See the edit, this works now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was very clear.
May I ask, what happens to the other elements of $U$?
Is it because of the following?
$$f^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(\bigcup_{u\in U}u)=(\bigcup_{c\neq u \in U} f^{-1}(u))\cup f^{-1}(c)
=\emptyset \cup X_1 = X_1$$

Comment: Yes, that is a very detailed reasoning of why it is true. Good job!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58803/discussion-between-malcolm-and-alec-diaz-arias).

Answer (score 1):

If $c \in U$, then $f^{-1}(U) = f^{-1}(\{c\})$ since $f(x) \in U$ if and only if $f(x) = c$.  Thus, in this case, $f^{-1}(U) = X_{1}$.  If $c \notin U$, then $f^{-1}(U) = \phi$.  $\mathcal{A}_{1}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra so $\{\phi,X_{1}\} \subseteq \mathcal{A}_{1}$ and so we're done.

Comment: Why is $f^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(\{c\})$? I don't understand your reasoning of $f(x)\in U$ iff $ f(x)=c$.

Comment: @Malcolm $f(X_1)=c$. i.e, $\forall x \in X_2 - \{c\}$, $f^{-1}(\{x\})=\emptyset$.